# Displaying certain fields when all fields are seleted SQL Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This is the script I have. I have to have all fields selected  but only have to show PartNumber and PartDesc.

```
SELECT UPPER (PartNumber) AS “Part Number”,
       UPPER (Partdesc) AS “Part Description”,
                             UnitsOnHand,
                             ItemClass,
                             Warehouse, 
                             UnitPrice                   
FROM Part

ORDER BY Warehouse DESC,
         UnitPrice ASC;
```

I am learning this for uni and am not 100% with it but am trying to learn.

Comment: This a question for a uni assignment ...  List all fields in the Part table with records listed in descending order of WarehouseNo and ascending order of UnitPrice. The recordset is ONLY to display the PartNumber and PartDesc data.
The PartNumber data is to be displayed in Upper Case, and the PartDesc data in Title Case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally your question is converted into below SQL, where I select all columns in the sub query and show only two

```
SELECT part_number, 
       part_description 
FROM   (SELECT Upper (partnumber) AS Part_Number, 
               INITCAP (partdesc)   AS Part_Description, 
               unitsonhand, 
               itemclass, 
               warehouse, 
               unitprice 
        FROM   part 
        ORDER  BY warehouse DESC, 
                  unitprice ASC);
```

Best Option is to do

```
SELECT Upper (partnumber) AS Part_Number, 
       Initcap (partdesc)   AS Part_Description 
FROM   part 
ORDER  BY warehouse DESC, 
          unitprice ASC;
```

Or even you can have a view

Comment: Thanks realspirituals I used your script but modified slightly to show what was expected ... if its not exactly like what is expected i lose marks lol I just changed SELECT "Part Number","Part Description"